# SoapUI - force endpoint URL when using testrunner.bat

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to run a SoapUI test-suite against two different endpoints and I do this by triggering two testrunner command and supply two different "-e" argument values.

The problem is that each of my test cases uses one API that I am testing, for which I do need to use the endpoint that is being passed under -e argument, and another API that should remain static. (The 2nd API is a helper API which sets up the environment for the first API to be able to work). So if I use the -e argument it breaks my tests because it forces the 2nd API to the same endpoint as the first API.

What I've tried so far is using the following groovy script to force endpoint value for specific Test Steps, however it's being ignored or maybe the script runs before the endpoints gets set, I'm not sure.

TestSuite setup script:

```
def testCases = testSuite.getTestCaseList()

for(testCase in testCases)
{
    def testSteps = testCase.getTestStepList() 

    for(testStep in testSteps)
    {
        if(testStep.name == "my name")
        {
            testStep.setPropertyValue('endpoint','http://force.it');
        }
    }
}
```

What else can I do to overcome this issue to avoid duplicating my tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're right seems that `e` argument overrides all endpoints inclusive the ones you set in the setup script.

Then I purpose  the follow approach for your case. SOAPUI as probably you already know has properties at different levels (testSuite, testCase, project, global) and you can use this properties to share information between your tests.

The thing is that you can use this properties to set your endpoints and pass the properties values in the testrunner command.

Set the endpoint for all your test request which test your 1st API using a global property:

`${#Project#endpointAPI1}`

[image]

And for the 2nd API set the endpoint url as:

`${#Project#endpointAPI2}`

Note: If you don't want to set the endpoints one by one you can use a groovy script testStep similar to the one you show in your question.

Once this is set, then you can invoke the testrunner for your both cases using the properties:

Then to test your cases you can add the follow properties, with `-P` properties are added at project level.

First endpoint for api1

`-PendpointAPI1=http://one_endpointAPI1.com -PendpointAPI2=http://endpointAPI2.com`

Second endpoint for api1

`-PendpointAPI1=http://second_endpointAPI1.com -PendpointAPI2=http://endpointAPI2.com`

Note that I use also a variable for endpoint API2 however if this is static and not change between both tests instead of using `${#Project#endpointAPI2}` you can set directly the url for this service and pass only the property `-PendpointAPI1`.

Hope it helps,

Comment: thank you for this answer, I ended up using -P as you suggested

Comment: @AlexE I don't know if there is a better workaround but this way works... nice to help you `:)`